# Variables and functions from String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

For instance, we have a variable and a function named `foo` and `plus`:

`var foo = 2`;

`var plus = function(a,b){return a+b;}`

and we have a string:

`var s = '1 plus foo';`

and now I want this string `s` *convert* to an array:

`var array = [1, plus, foo]);`

Please note this is **not `[1, 'plus', 'foo']`** which conversion is rather easy and I know the way.

So, consequently, my Question would be

**how to obtain a value(function) itself from strings?**

and also please note that using `eval` to solve this issue is invalid since **the purpose is not to evaluate but to construct an array** from the string.

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Since I use node.js

The global object is `global`
and 
it seems
`global.foo` and `var foo` is different.

I felt that before this Question and that is why I asked here.

`[1, global['plus'], global['foo']]` should be invalid answer.

Comment: Have you tried `s.split(' ')`? Then you can call `foo` with `window[s.split(' ')[2]]()`

Comment: You can put `s` and `foo` in an object then use bracket notation.

Comment: There is no *syntactic sugar* to help you with this, so just split, traverse and build your array on the way.

Comment: @elclanrs: way to be cryptic.

Comment: Just trying to be specific, it's easier to find info if you look for the right terms, ie https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Comment: The global object is global and it seems `global.foo` and `var foo` is different.

I felt that before this Question and that is why I asked here.

`[1, global['plus'], global['foo']]` should be invalid answer.

Comment: The only reason I've got 2 downvotes of this question is some guys here felt uncomfortable with the fact their comment is not appreciated well by me. It's not fair, so I will report to Moderators here.

Comment: tewathia, if you think your answer is valid, why don't you put it as an answer not such a comment. So that I could downvote  your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My self answer:

`var G = {};`

`var foo = G.foo = 2`;

`var plus = G.plus = function(a,b){return a+b;}`

and we have a string:

`var s = '1 plus foo';`

and now I want this string `s` *convert* to an array:

`var array = [1, G['plus'], G['foo']];`

In this way, we can avoid Global Variables and keep `var foo` format, and at the same time, allow the value accessible with G object + ['string'].

Answer (score 0):

if you **do** `s.split(' ');`, you can use the strings in the array to call the requested functions:

```
window['plus']() // Call your functions like this.
```

Or to set them in an array:

```
var array = [1, window['plus'], window['foo']];
```

Then you'll have the function references stored in `array`.

Comment: Well, I think I mentioned that the purpose is NOT to evaluate function.

Comment: This is not `eval`. Read "bracket notation". Object keys **are** strings.

Comment: @KenOKABE: Then leave out the `()`. `window['plus']` is the only way to access that function from a string. Your functions are simply properties on the `window` object.

Comment: Ok sure, thank you. In fact, I use node.js, what is the gloal object? `window` is for browser. I know this is another question, and should have included in my Q.

Comment: @KenOKABE: The Node.js equivalent of `window` is `global`,

Comment: Great, I will edit my Q. Your answer is checked. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried `var foo = 2;console.log(global['foo']);` and the result is `undefined`

Comment: Hm, and if you leave out the `var`?

Comment: Especially, in strict mode, it is not the correct manner. `global.foo =2` or `window.foo = 2` should work, and I somehow knew that, probably that is why I didn't come to think to use object bracket notation way.

Comment: Yea, it was more of a curiosity thing :P
So, it works as desired, now?

Comment: Well, for sure I have an option to rewrite my whole variable to change  to `global.foo`, and it's rather my purpose or curiosity if there's a way to do that without rewrite them all wrapped under `global` or some other object. Your opinion shall be - impossible correct? Since you said  `window['plus'] is the only way to access that function from a string`